# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redisgraph'

Tags: python, redis, redisgraph

I am running into an error while importing `redisgraph` in python but `import redis` is working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `redisgraph` pip package. Do this in your terminal

```
pip install redisgraph
```

[source](https://github.com/RedisGraph/redisgraph-py)